Initialize third party Android native SDK for authentication on React Native Expo managed flow
I'm developing a React Native app using expo and need to integrate a native SDK for android that needs to initialize in the MainApplication onCreate method, as such:
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    SoLoader.init(this, false)
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      load()
    }
    ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.onApplicationCreate(this)
    ThirPartySdk.initialize(this, "com.mycompany.nameofmyapp.MainActivity")
  }

I do not have access to the SDK code or can modify it.
This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "name-of-my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.3",
    "@pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native": "^1.3.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.79",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-image": "~1.13.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.16.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "pusher-js": "^8.4.0-rc2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.8.6",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "jsdoc": "~4.0.2"
  },
  "//": "Override vulnerable dependency until expo updates it.",
  "overrides": {
    "@expo/image-utils": {
      "semver": "7.5.2"
    }
  },
  "private": true
}

This is my app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "name-of-my-app",
    "slug": "name-of-my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/logo.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "scheme": "https",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/logo.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.mycompany.nameofmyapp"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/logo.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.mycompany.nameofmyapp"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/logo.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "expo-secure-store",
      [
        "expo-font",
        {
          "fonts": [
            "assets/fonts/myriad_condensed.otf",
            "assets/fonts/myriad_bold_condensed.otf"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      }
    }
  }
}

My app/AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme" android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data android:name="sdk_ai" android:value="xxxxx"/>
      <meta-data android:name="sdk_ck" android:value="xxxxx"/>
      <meta-data android:name="sdk_cs" android:value="xxxxx"/>
      <meta-data android:name="sdk_en" android:value="sandbox"/>
      <meta-data android:name="sdk_ma" android:value="com.mycompany.nameofmyapp.MainActivity"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="false"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.mycompany.nameofmyapp"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
</manifest>

The third party SDK is supposed to redirect to the browser for authentication and then redirects back to the provided activity in the second parameter. I know for a fact that the SDK works as intended as I tested it on a "hello world" android project.
The problem I'm facing is that when the application is running using npx expo run:android this redirection is completely ignored, if I intentionally remove configuration from the Android Manifest it throws an exception, so the code is being executed. If I run the app with android studio the redirection does happens but after redirecting back to the app I get the following error (1):
Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
If I run the app with the suggested npx react-native start then we're back to the initialization getting ignored (as npx expo run:android). After running the previous command, I get 2 identical apps installed in the device, running the 2nd one triggers the redirection and the intent back from the browser ask to select one of the 2 apps, but no information about the authenticated user exists selecting neither of the 2 options (the first in the list just don't have any auth information but opens as if everything is ok and the 2nd in the list shows "Unmatched Route" (2)). I did a release build with ./gradlew assembleRelease and the same thing happens as with npx expo run:android.
The question is: Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do with an Expo project and in case it is not supported what are possible alternatives or work-arounds.
Error running with android studio (1):
Not running metro
Error when selecting 2nd app of the list after a redirection (2):
Unmatched route
Thanks in advance, any insight will be appreciated!
